# Referencing an external project from a sub project in gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have a project setup like so where my projects are all in sibling folders relative to one another:

```
+ mainApp
+ mylib
+ mylib2
```

mainApp references the mylib library project that is not in its root with the following in my settings.gradle:

```
include ':app', ':mylib'
project(':mylib').projectDir=new File('..\\mylib')
```

However, the issue is that the mylib project depends on another lib - mylib2.  I can essentially do the same thing and reference mylib2 using settings.gradle and building mylib works fine.

The problem is when I try to build mainApp, it cannot find mylib2 because the settings.gradle of a sub-project is not ran, only the root settings.gradle is ran.  So, when the build.gradle file of mylib references mylib2, it cannot find mylib2.

I do not want to add a reference to mylib2 from mainApp, I want mylib2 to be brought in by mylib.

Is there a way to bring in mylib2 from the build.gradle file of mylib ?

Comment: Isn't `includeFlat` what you are looking for? https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#includeFlat(java.lang.String[])

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a wrong understanding of subprojects.
Every "Project Tree" has a rootProject. This rootProject is the only project that should have a settings.gradle wich includes all subprojects. So if all of your 3 Projects belog together, then they must all be included in the settings.gradle.

References to other foreign project should be added as dependencies. Note that you can only reference Artifacts this way.

You did not make it very clear, but it seems like you want to use the project "mylib" as a Library for the source code of "mainApp"

If those are java projects you can simply add the jar file produced by "mylib" to the compile configuration of "mainApp":

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir:'../myLib/build/libs', include : '**/*.jar')
}
```

For other languages you have to use the language specific support for that language.